# UITableViewCell's contentView add UIScrollView, won't perform segue

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a subclassed UITableViewCell, if I add a UIScrollView to cell's contentView, can't perform the segue, if I comment the line, it can perform the segue.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setup];
}

- (void)setup
{
    UIScrollView *scrolView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))];
    scrolView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds)+kButtonWidth, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));
    scrolView.delegate = self;
    scrolView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
//    [self.contentView addSubview:scrolView];
}
```

Comment: Where are you performing your segue? If its at cells click you have to give it on Tap of scrollview.!

Comment: How to do that? Add a tap gesture recogniser to the scrollview?

Comment: Yes, you can do that or else you can place transparent button out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a scroll view that is the full size of the cell in the content view, on top of all other views in the cell. It's covering them up, so no clicks get through. I suspect you want to add a scroll view as a container for your other views. I don't know how you could do that with all the standard views that the table view base class manages for you. You'd have to somehow override the behavior of the base class and change the content view into a scroll-view.

Alternatively you could do what you are doing, but then you would need to replace all the standard table view cell fields and behaviors with your own, which would be nearly impossible.

Adding a scroll view to a table view cell is probably a bad idea. The table view itself is a subclass of a scroll view, and it will be very hard/impossible to sort out which gestures are supposed to scroll the table view and which are supposed to scroll a cell. The only way I could see that working is if the cell's scroll view is limited to horizontal scrolling.

Comment: I am following this tutorial: http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/reproducing-the-ios-7-mail-apps-interface/